# script <путь> not found

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

Хочу cконвертировать .py в .exe, но возникает ошибка. Я вообще не понимаю, в чём может быть проблема. Прошу помочь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно скопировать <название скрипта>.py из папки venv в папку проекта